# Matching based on conditional data

Tags: r

I have two Dfs with multiple rows and columns. I want to see if Df1$Name matches Df2$Name.  If it matches, I want it to take match value and create a new variable in DF3. But if it doesn't match, I want to paste the value from Df1.  The issue is that Df1 has 270 observations and Df2 has 277.

See example:

```
Df1
       Name      
       Natalie   
       Desmond,James   
       Kylie     

Df2
        Name      
         <Na>
        Desmond,James  
        <Na>
 Df3    
        Merged_name
        Natalie
        Desomond,James
        Kylie
```

I've tried:

```
Df3$Merged_name <- ifelse(Df1Name %in% Df$Name 
              & !is.na(Df2$Name), Df1$Name 
                 , Df2$Name)
```

I get an error saying that the longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object 
length which I'm assuming is due to the varying observations. Do I have to separate rows that have more than one name in it(i.e. separate_rows())? If so, how do I re-merge back together?

Comment: Try a `full_join` out of the `tidyverse`

Comment: Thanks akash, I'm not familiar with the full_join function.  Care to share some code? Also, it doesn't answer my original query..care to elaborate on the full question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cbind.fill function which accepts binding of columns given different row numbers and then you do the conditional scenario you gave;

```
library(dplyr)
library(rowr)

Df1 <-
  data.frame(
    Name = c("Natalie", "Desmond,James", "Kylie"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

Df2 <-
  data.frame(
    Name = c(NA_character_, "Desmond,James", NA_character_, "Test"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

# Binding data by column and renaming similar column names
cbind.fill(Df1 %>% rename(Name1 = Name), Df2 %>% rename(Name2 = Name), fill = NA) %>%
  mutate(Name = coalesce(Name2, Name1)) %>% # Conditional logic given
  select(Name)

# Name
# Natalie
# Desmond,James
# Kylie
# Name1
```

Comment: Nareman,  I get an error in the code I ran using my variables names. It states that Error: unexpected '=' in  mutate(Name ="

Comment: Do you have an object with the name Name?

Comment: No it's the variable that I used for my merged dataset..df3 in my example above.

Comment: Can you copy the line of code after changing the names of variables in it?

Comment: cbind.fill(Df1 %>% rename(Name1 = Df3$Name), Df2 %>% rename(Name2 = Df3$Name), fill = NA) %>%
  mutate( Df3$Name = coalesce(Name2,Name1)) %>% select(Df3$Name)

Comment: No need for the $ remove them all and it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205257/discussion-between-dr-e77-and-nareman-darwish).

Comment: FYI to store the output you just need to: Df3 <- cbind.fill(Df1 %>% rename(Name1 = Name), Df2 %>% rename(Name2 = Name), fill = NA) %>%
  mutate(Name = coalesce(Name2, Name1)) %>% 
  select(Name)